# NSTableView has no row selected by default

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

I have a cell based NSTableView.  When it is first displayed none of the rows are selected.  I would like the first one to be selected by default.  Is there a setting in Interface Builder that I missed to get this to happen?

I tried "setAllowsEmptySelection" but that didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it programmatically by using

[selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/selectRowIndexes%3abyExtendingSelection%3a)

Comment: @JPC: Make sure you connected your outlet to your table view. If it's not connected, the outlet property holds `nil`, and sending a message to it will do nothing.

Comment: This was the answer.  I was just doing it too early

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried unchecking `Selection:Empty` in the attributes pane? If you uncheck that option in the NIB, it should "just work."

Comment: Empty isn't checked.  Only Type Select is checked

Comment: Are you using an NSArrayController?

Comment: Nope, just using a data source